# How to use a DSP Slice in FPGAs (Artix7)

Tags: signal-processing, vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I recently started programming on FPGAs and i have to work with the onboard DSP Slices.
My instantiation is copied from the user guide, but I dont know exactly how to do the behavioral part of it. There is also a little working code, but I dont know how to combine them :(
Please help me guys I am quite desperate...
btw i use VHDL for develloping

```
Library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.vcomponents.all;
library UNIMACRO;
use unimacro.Vcomponents.all;

ADDMACC_MACRO_inst : ADDMACC_MACRO
  generic map (
    DEVICE => "7SERIES", -- Target Device: "7SERIES", "VIRTEX6", "SPARTAN6"
    LATENCY => 4, -- Desired clock cycle latency, 1-4
    WIDTH_PREADD => 25, -- Pre-Adder input bus width, 1-25
    WIDTH_MULTIPLIER => 18, -- Multiplier input bus width, 1-18
    WIDTH_PRODUCT => 48) -- MACC output width, 1-48
  port map (
    PRODUCT => PRODUCT, -- MACC result output, width defined by WIDTH_PRODUCT generic
    MULTIPLIER => MULTIPLIER, -- Multiplier data input, width determined by WIDTH_MULTIPLIER generic
    PREADDER1 => PREADDER1, -- Preadder data input, width determined by WIDTH_PREADDER generic
    PREADDER2 => PREADDER2, -- Preadder data input, width determined by WIDTH_PREADDER generic
    CARRYIN => CARRYIN, -- 1-bit carry-in input
    CE => CE, -- 1-bit input clock enable
    CLK => CLK, -- 1-bit clock input
    LOAD => LOAD, -- 1-bit accumulator load input
    LOAD_DATA => LOAD_DATA, -- Accumulator load data input, width defined by WIDTH_PRODUCT generic
    RST => RST -- 1-bit input active high synchronous reset
  );
-- End of ADDMACC_MACRO_inst instantiation
```

And there is some working code, i have written so far:

```
entity test is
  Port (clk : inout std_logic;
        oclk : out std_logic;
end test;
architecture Behavioral of test is
begin
  oclk <= not clk;
  process
  begin
    clk <= '1';
    wait for 5 ns;
    clk <= '0';
    wait for 5 ns;
  end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: You may be able to avoid instantiating the DSP slice if your operation(s) is simple enough for the synthesizer to infer. If you're doing a common MAC operation, for instance, it can usually be written algebraically in VHDL. That will eliminate the hassle of connecting everything that the full library component requires. The Xilinx synthesis guide gives more details on this.

Comment: well later on i need about 200 dsp slices... so i guess i have to instantiate them. My task is to multiply big integers and i have to divide them in little pieces.

Comment: You need to read the user guide to understand what the DSP slices do. You can find the virtex-6 version at http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug369.pdf (you can still instantiate a virtex-6 dsp48e1 in 7-series parts) and with a little searching you should be able to find the updated 7-series version. It should be clear how to set the attributes if you know what you want the block to do and what the block can do. Your "working code" is just a clock generator; it doesn't shed any light on what you're actually trying to DO with the DSP slices.